# TypeScript: typings based on object keys that come from enum

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an enum. I'd like to use its values to create typings for an object where these values became keys. The following example demonstrates what I'd like to achieve:

```
export enum MyEnum {
  PROP_1 = "prop 1",
  PROP_2 = "prop 2",
  // ... more props
}

export interface MyInterface {
  property: {
    "prop 1": boolean,
    "prop 2": boolean,
    // ... more props
  }
}
```

It works fine, but I'd like to avoid repeating all the properties from enum in the interface.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
export enum MyEnum {
  PROP_1 = "prop 1",
  PROP_2 = "prop 2",
  // ... more props
}

// PSEUDOCODE!
export interface MyInterface {
  property: {
    [values from MyEnum]: boolean
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @jcalz for the solution:

```
enum MyEnum {
  PROP_1 = "prop 1",
  PROP_2 = "prop 2",
  // ... more props
}

interface PropertyInterface extends Record<MyEnum, boolean> {}

interface MyInterface {
  property: PropertyInterface,
}
```

It works good, according to what I wrote before, but I've just realized that I forgot to mention that I need all these properties to be optional.

The given solution works if a variable that implements `MyInterface` is defined as follows:

```
// VALID!
const myVariable: MyInterface = {
  property: {
    "prop 1": true,
    "prop 2": true,
  },
};
```

But does not work if I omit some keys as follows:

```
// INVALID :(
const myVariable: MyInterface = {
  property: {
    "prop 1": true,
  },
};
```

Comment: `export interface MyInterface extends Record<MyEnum, true> {}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I've just realized that I have a more specific requirement. I've updated my post.

Comment: `interface PropertyInterface extends Partial<Record<MyEnum, boolean>> { }`

Comment: Let me know if this question stabilizes and you want me to put in an official answer (or someone else can do it if they get here first)

Comment: The question is updated. I'm not going to add more requirements :)

Answer (score 68):

Support for this was added in TypeScript 2.9 as part of [expanded key support mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types).  Specifically:

> A mapped type `{ [P in K]: XXX }` permits any `K` assignable to `string | number | symbol`.

That means you can make a type alias to a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) with enum values as the key:

```
enum MyEnum {
  PROP_1 = "prop 1",
  PROP_2 = "prop 2",
  // ... more props
}

type MyEnumValuedKeys = { [K in MyEnum]: boolean; }
// identical to 
// type MyEnumValuedKeys = {
//  "prop 1": boolean;
//  "prop 2": boolean;
//  ... more props
// }
```

You can make mapped type properties optional by adding a `?` after the index-like key:

```
type OptionalMyEnumValuedKeys = { [K in MyEnum]?: boolean; }
// identical to 
// type MyEnumValuedKeys = {
//  "prop 1"?: boolean;
//  "prop 2"?: boolean;
//  ... more props
// }
```

So you can use `OptionalMyEnumValuedKeys` as your `PropertyInterface`.  It is a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) and not an interface.  That [usually doesn't matter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases) but in case it does, TypeScript 2.8 introduced the abilitity to [extend certain concrete mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604), so you can get an interface like this:

```
type OptionalMyEnumValuedKeys = { [K in MyEnum]?: boolean; };
interface PropertyInterface extends OptionalMyEnumValuedKeys {} // add no properties
```

This could also be accomplished by using the built-in [`Record`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1379-L1384) and [`Partial`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1351-L1356) type aliases:

```
interface PropertyInterface extends Partial<Record<MyEnum, boolean>> {}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is not working for me.  I'm getting `MyEnumValuedKeys = {}` when I inspect

Comment: [Really?](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClACgJQPJYD6AjFALxQBEADgE4D21UxlANBtvkQEzlV2Mo3NhwD0oqADppUCPVrAoA6gGc0AXzRoALnGqL4SSADUAhgBswwACYBpYHBV8UUANq2oASxCxEyALoAXFAARvT05sCmIADcUJo6eop41Nqe9CAWhshmljb2js5uHt6+RhD+APzBYRFRsfFa3trAtABmpgDGilgM+rS6AJIgLe1disAAHi0g1k4paRlZfiYWVnYOTijqUOJQptbWUCD0Sn2tacBqQA) 

Answer (score 5):

It's been a long time since asked, but if you end up here this may be what you're after:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  PROP_1 = "prop 1",
  PROP_2 = "prop 2",
  // ... more props
}

interface MyInterface {
  property: {
    [MyEnum.PROP_1]: boolean,
    [MyEnum.PROP_2]: boolean,
    // ... more props
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14682#issuecomment-286999967