# Using a type as indexer

Tags: typescript

I have set an enum like this:

```
type Mode = 'Auto' | 'Manual';
```

I now want to create an object where they keys must be one of the strings from `Mode` enum.

I tried this:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  fields: {
    [index: ExecutionMode]: string[]
  } = {
    Auto: [],
    Manual: [],
  };
```

However this gives me error:

> [ts] An index signature parameter type cannot be a type alias. Consider writing '[index: string]: string[]' instead.

Is this possible in typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: typings based on object keys that come from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071366/typescript-typings-based-on-object-keys-that-come-from-enum/53084294#53084294)

Comment: Why you call this enum `type Mode = 'Auto' | 'Manual';` when it is a union? Did you mis-call it, or did you wrote wrong code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are

```
type Mode = 'Auto' | 'Manual';

type Fields = {
    [K in Mode]: string[]
}

// inside your class:
fields: Fields = {
    Auto: [],
    Manual: []
}
```

BTW, what you are calling "enum" is a "union".